# Изменить валидность email вердпресс

Tags: wordpress

Как в вордпресс отключить проверку на правильность написания почты при регистр, отзывах и прочее, и необязательно с **" @ "**  пусть пользователь пишет что хочет

Comment: Как может быть почта без `@`?

Comment: @mihdan там цель, скорее всего, не требовать введение email при регистрации, а в WP он используется как идентификатор пользователя, то есть само поле обязательное и отключить его нельзя

Comment: Ну тогда можно генерить мыло динамически типа `timestamp@domain.com`